# How to uniquely identify animations?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to access `Animation`'s but so far the only method I could think of was:

```
tool

...

    set_meta("animation_path",["NodePath/to/AnimationPlayer","Animation Name"])

    var ani_data=get_meta("animation_path")
    var animation=get_node(ani_data[0]).get_animation(ani_data[1])
```

but the problem is that if I change the Animation Name I'll have to reset the value, so is there no way to store a unique id for `Animation` resource?

I tried storing `get_instance_id()` & using `instance_from_id()` but that doesn't work when I restart the game engine

Comment: Hi, can you expand on what the purpose of and how you will use the uniquely identified animation?

Comment: @hola take for example a texture resource, whenever I change the position of a sprite within the texture then I will need to go back to all the animations and change the `region_rect` and in that case I would need a reference to find all the animations (all this is being done in `tool` mode)

Answer (score 1):

**If the `Animation` is saved**

Given that `Animation` is a `Resource`, I believe you can use the `resource_path` (given the `Animation` is saved).

The `resource_path` represents *where* the `Resource` is saved, and thus it persists when you restart the game engine.

Also, it would be unique for each `Resource` (it is possible to have multiple `Resource`s saved in the same file, but then the `resource_path` of each `Resource` points to a sub-resource of the file).

And yes, the `resource_path` does not change when you rename the `Animation`.

---

The other idea that comes to mind is that the `Animation` itself has metadata which you could use.

---

If you will not be using the animation name, you would have to iterate over the `Animation`s of the `AnimationPlayer` to find the one you want.

*I suppose that if you use the `resource_path`, you could load it and get the animation name form there. You could also be getting the same instance… That happens if you are getting it from cache.*

---

**If the `Animation` is not saved.**

First of all, storing metadata on the `Animation` should still work. Except, of course, it still means to iterate over the `Animation`s to find the correct one.

If the goal is to not do that, then you can hold a `Dictionary` with `String` for keys and `Animation`s as values, and keep it somewhere you know there is only one instance. For example:

- Store it in an `EditorPlugin`.
- Store it in an Autoload.
- Store it in a specific `Resource` which you `preload`.
- Store it on a `const`. *Godot will admit `Dictionary` and `Array` as `const`s. Making them `const`s means you cannot set them… But they are still mutable. Furthermore, `const`s are shared among instances.*

Comment: In my case, the `Animation` is not being saved. in that case `resource_path` doesn't work
and as for metadata, I'm trying to store a reference to the `Animation` externally in some other resource/node so that wouldn't be feasible

Comment: I tried what you suggested & stored it inside an array : `self.set_meta("animation",[$AniPlayer.get_animation("New Anim"]))` and it works fine but the problem is that when I delete the `Animation` or the `AnimationPlayer` and then invoke `self.get_meta("animation")` it should technically return a null because the animation no longer exists but instead I get the animation itself as if it hasn't been deleted

Comment: @cakelover `Resource` extends `Reference`, they are reference counted, and you are holding a reference… That is a job fo `WeakRef`.

Comment: I [tried](https://pastecode.io/s/9gm6bo4b) using WeakRef but it gives the same problem